# Implementing web application for different users in spring mvc

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

I want to create a web application for two set of users, 'admin' and 'normal user'. There are five pages in my application.

Let us imagine them as follows 'login,pageA,pageB,pageC,pageD'. Once user logs in, he has access to pageA,pageB,pageC,pageD.

But now I want to restrict the access to 'normal user'. Only 'admin' gets to access to page A,B,C,D whereas 'normal user' can access only page A,B.

How can I achieve this using spring-mvc. Is there any Spring bean configuration for implementing user privileges in web application?

Answer (score 0):

Most of peaple do it in spring-security.

Answer (score 0):

Use spring security for this purpose.. follow tutorial below..

```
http://krams915.blogspot.com/2012/01/spring-security-31-implement_5023.html
```

Alternatively, Apache Shiro can be used..Spring has also first class integration with shiro